# Dotted lines with Overpic

Tags: overpic

A normal line within the `overpic` environment can be placed with:

```
\put( 122.00,  82.00) {\color{blue} \line(1,0){ 23}}
```

Is there a way to draw `- -` dashed/dotted lines with `overpic`?

**Research:**

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/overpic/overpic.pdf) isn't that good for referencing

Comment: \put(coordinates){\tikz \draw[dashed,blue](start)--(end);}

Comment: Without supplementary packages you could use `\multiput`: MWE: `\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(10,0.1)
\multiput(0.25,0)(0.5,0){20}{\line(0,0){0.1}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}` But if there is nothing against it I would also use `tikz`.

Comment: @Colo could you give an example with values placed inside the placeholders?

Comment: @3kstc

     `\begin{overpic}{example-image-c}\put(20,30){\tikz \draw[dashed,red] (0,0)--(5,3);}\end{overpic}`